# python replace() function, should I check first if what i want to replace is a substring of the string?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to replace the '/' character of a string but it may be or not in the string, what is the best option in this case?

This code:

```
text = text.replace('/', os.linesep) if '/' in text else text
```

Or simply this one?:

```
text = text.replace('/', os.linesep)
```

Would the first statement help to not waste time "trying to replace"?

Comment: It's quicker to just do the replace. Think of it this way. If you say `if '/' in text` you have to look through each character. And if you do a replace it has to look through each character. So you're actually doubling the computation time by checking if it exists first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said the check is not required. But it might help if you may have a lot cases where there are a lot of strings where the substring is not there. In that case you might get a good amount of performance gain. Checking it using the timeit module:

Comparison where there a lot of cases where the substring is not present in the string. Note that there is a big difference in performance.

```
➜  ~ python3.5 -m timeit '"vxnxikmhdc".replace("a", "b") if "a" in "vxnxikmhdc" else "vxnxikmhdc"'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0524 usec per loop
➜  ~ python3.5 -m timeit '"vxnxikmhdc".replace("a", "b")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.207 usec per loop
```

Comparison where substring is present in the string. Note that there is very little difference in performance.

```
➜  ~ python3.5 -m timeit '"vxnxikmhdc".replace("x", "j")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.245 usec per loop
➜  ~ python3.5 -m timeit '"vxnxikmhdc".replace("x", "j") if "x" in "vxnxikmhdc" else "vxnxikmhdc"'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.308 usec per loop
```